# In C++, when an element of an array is used multiple times in a loop, is it better to assign it to an other element?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vectorization

Let's say I have a loop that will do some math on an array `x`. Is it better to assign a temporary double inside the loop at each iteration or should I use the `array[i]` every time?

By better I mean performance-wise using C++. I wonder if C++ has some vectorization or cash optimization that I'm ruining?

Also what if I call a function using this array and I might need values of a function multiple times, so I usually do the same with functions. I assume this would be better than calling the function many times.

How about if the loop uses `omp parallel`, I assume this should be safe, correct?

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    double xi = X[i];
    double fi = f(xi);
    t[i] = xi*xi + fi + xi/fi;
}
```

Comment: Using temporary might avoid extra load due to aliasing issue (if `f(xi)` **can** modify `X[i]`).

Comment: In addition, `f(xi)` might be not "pure" and return different values each time (as `rand()` for example).

Comment: You **only** start worrying about micro-optimisations when you have **measured** your performance and found it not up to **stated requirements**.

Comment: @n.m. Agree - important keyword is *'micro'*, though, some general optimisation patterns still should be considered right from the start, e. g. using (and implementing) move-semantics, where reasonable, `reserve`ing `std::vector`'s capacity, if size is known in advance, using the result of `std::map::find` instead of doing a second lookup, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern compilers (last 10 years) will optimise it out. Don't worry about it.

EDIT:

This has been discussed in StackOverflow a few times:
[Will compiler optimize and reuse variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904905/will-compiler-optimize-and-reuse-variable)
[In C++, should I bother to cache variables, or let the compiler do the optimization? (Aliasing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898371/in-c-should-i-bother-to-cache-variables-or-let-the-compiler-do-the-optimizat)

This official [documentation explains](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) it, IMHO it is
`-fmerge-all-constants`  `-fivopts` and maybe `-ftree-coalesce-vars` clang and MSCV have similar options, feel free to research them yourself or link them here.

In practice, when a compiler sees a memory read (a variable, or array value) it will read it into a register, and unless that not marked as `volatile`, the compiler can assume it did not change, and will not issue instructions to re-read it.

Having said the magical `volatile` word: It should not be used for threading. It should be used for hardware mapped memory (for example, video card memory or external ports).

Comment: Arrays – sure. Matter might change, though, if using `std::map` instead; index lookup (`operator[]`) is complex and even might change the data (if element is not found) – would the compiler be able to prove that dropping second lookup wouldn't discard any visible side effects? Only then it would be allowed to optimise it away...

Comment: @elcuco do you have a source for this? im really curious how it works.

Comment: @Aconcagua if the `[]` operator is marked `const` then there is no reason to re-read the value (call that operator).

Comment: @elcuco Have you looked at `std::map`? It doesn't even provide a `const` version of...

Comment: if the `[]` operator is not `const`, than the compiler will need to re-read the value, just as you suggest (internal implementation can return a different value after each read, that is correct).

Answer (score 5):

elcuco is correct. Any compiler worth it's salt will be able to optimise out something this trivial. What matters here is code readability, personally i find `X[i]` to be a little easier to look at in this situation.

I will note that if you are repeatedly making very long statements i.e `X.something.something.darkside[i][j]` it might make sense to use a clearly named reference i.e `auto & the_emperor = X.something.something.darkside[i][j]`.